# Trying to sort my movie titles alphabetically and then display them along with one of the ratings in my rating Array

Tags: java

I've attempted to sort the code and swapping titles that are not in alphabetical order and then display the results but no luck. No errors but the movie titles will not display as the arrays are unused. Not sure what I did wrong. I've tried googling this but for my case I don't know what I'm missing.

Main

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package movieapp;

/**
 *
 * @author T
 */
import java.util.*;
public class Movieapp {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        moviearray arrMovie;
        arrMovie = new moviearray(5);
        int nElems = 5;

        String movieArr[] = {"Lion king", "Avengers", "Interstellar", "Batman", "13 Hours"};
        int ratingArr[] = {4, 5, 8, 10, 3};

    arrMovie.sort();
    arrMovie.display();
    }


}
```

Movie class

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package movieapp;

/**
 *
 * @author T
 */
public class movie {

    String movie;
    int rating;

    movie(String m, int r){
        this.movie = m;
        this.rating = r;


    }

    public void info(){
        System.out.println("The movie " + this.movie + " is rated a " + this.rating);
    }

}
```

Movie Array class

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package movieapp;

/**
 *
 * @author T
 */
public class moviearray {

    private movie[] arrMovie;
    private int nElems = 0;

    moviearray(int size) {
        arrMovie = new movie[size];
        nElems = 0;
    }

    public void sort() {
        int out;
        int in;
        for (out = nElems - 1; out > 1; out--) {
            for (in = 0; in < out; in++) {
                if (arrMovie[in].movie.compareToIgnoreCase(arrMovie[in + 1].movie) > 0) {
                    swap(in, in + 1);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void swap(int x, int y) {
        movie temp = arrMovie[x];
        arrMovie[x] = arrMovie[y];
        arrMovie[y] = temp;
    }

    public void display() {
        for (int i = 0; i < nElems; i++) {
            arrMovie[i].info();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edited Movieapp Class and Moviearray, added a set and get**

**movieapp**

```
 */
package movieapp;

/**
 *
 * @author T
 */
import java.util.*;
public class Movieapp {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        moviearray arrMovie;
        arrMovie = new moviearray(5);
        int nElems = 5;

        String movieArr[] = {"Lion king", "Avengers", "Interstellar", "Batman", "13 Hours"};
        int ratingArr[] = {4, 5, 8, 10, 3};

        for(int i = 0; i < nElems; i++){
            arrMovie.setElement(i, movieArr[i], ratingArr[i]);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < nElems; i++){
            arrMovie.getElement(i).info();
        }
    }


}
```

**moviearray**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package movieapp;

/**
 *
 * @author T
 */
public class moviearray {

    public movie[] arrMovie;
    public int nElems = 0;

    moviearray(int size) {
        arrMovie = new movie[size];
        nElems = 0;
    }


    public void setElement(int index, String movie, int rating){
        arrMovie[index]= new movie(movie, rating);
    }

    public movie getElement(int index){
        return arrMovie[index];
    }

    public void sort() {
        int out;
        int in;
        for (out = nElems - 1; out > 1; out--) {
            for (in = 0; in < out; in++) {
                if (arrMovie[in].movie.compareToIgnoreCase(arrMovie[in + 1].movie) > 0) {
                    swap(in, in + 1);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void swap(int x, int y) {
        movie temp = arrMovie[x];
        arrMovie[x] = arrMovie[y];
        arrMovie[y] = temp;
    }

    public void display() {
        for (int i = 0; i < nElems; i++) {
            arrMovie[i].info();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDd0A.png)

Just need to get it in alphabetical order now.

Comment: You have implemented a `moviearray`, but you have given it no way of assigning values for its `arrMovie` property. Instead of what you have, make it so the `moviearray` constructor has parameter of type `movie[]` and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

u did it wrong. u create ur object but u dont assgin value to this object.

```
moviearray arrMovie;
arrMovie = new moviearray(5);
arrMovie.nElems = 5;
arrMovie.arrMovie = {
   new Movie("Lion king",4), 
   new Movie("Avengers",5),
   new Movie("Interstellar",8),
   new Movie("Batman",10),
   new Movie("13 hours",3)
};
```

u have to change nElems and arrMovie to public or add setter for that fields.

#### u had a bad design i think, but this change solve ur problem

Answer (score 0):

You could use `java.util.stream.Stream` to build the collection of movies, then use that API to sort them by title. The `moviearray` object is unused in this scenario.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream<movie> movies = Stream.of(
            new movie("Lion King", 4), 
            new movie("Avengers", 5),
            new movie("Interstellar", 8),
            new movie("Batman", 10),
            new movie("13 Hours", 3)
        );
        List<movie> sortedMovies = movies.sorted((m1, m2) -> m1.movie.compareTo(m2.movie)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        sortedMovies.forEach(m -> m.info());
    }
```

OUTPUT

```
The movie 13 Hours is rated a 3
The movie Avengers is rated a 5
The movie Batman is rated a 10
The movie Interstellar is rated a 8
The movie Lion King is rated a 4
```

*[edit] updated to match the desired output using the `info()` method of the `movie` object.*